# I am getting 2 different behaviours in ShaderMask in iOS and android in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

With the below code, I am getting 2 different responses on both platforms.

[image]

```
Positioned.fill(
  child: ShaderMask(
             shaderCallback: (bounds) =>
             LinearGradient(colors: const [
                        Colors.pink,
                        Colors.pink,
                        Colors.blue,
                        Colors.blue,
                         ],
                        stops: [
                          0,
                          tVotes == 0
                          ? 0.0
                          : pollOption.votes / tVotes,
                           tVotes == 0 ? 0.0
                          : pollOption.votes / tVotes,
                          1
                         ],
                     ).createShader(bounds),
```

Tried adding different colors and stops but same response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.